# Can not run the MounteBank first example

Tags: mountebank

I tried to run the first example of MounteBank documentation but it fail. I followed the initial setup:

```js
imposters.ejs
{
  "imposters": [
    <% include originServer.ejs %>,
    <% include proxyServer.ejs %>
  ]
}
```

And after I ran:
`mb --configfile imposters.ejs --allowInjection --localOnly`

But I receive this error log:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in imposters.ejs while compiling ejs
```

I've tried to change the ejs include syntax to something like this:

```js
<% include 'originServer.ejs' %>,
<% include 'proxyServer.ejs' %>
OR
<% include('originServer.ejs'); %>,
<% include ('proxyServer.ejs'); %>
```

But for each change the error is:

```
Error: Could not find the include file...
```